# Modify the html with data retrieved by the controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The controller retrieve data from a request and I have to update the html/input with the data retrieved. Sorry the question is this code doesn't work and I'm not figuring it out.

```js
exports.SearchBarController = function($scope, $http) {
  
  $scope.update = function() {
    var query = encodeURIComponent($scope.searchText);

    $http.
      get('/api/v1/product/text/' + query).
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.results = data.products;
      });
  };

  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$emit('SearchBarController');
  }, 0);
};
```

```html
<div class="search-bar-wrapper">
  <div ng-controller="SearchBarController">
      <input type="text" class="search-bar-input" ng-model="data.products" ng-        change="update()">
        <div class="product" ng-repeat="product in {{data.products}}">
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is your question?  What errors are you seeing?  What do you want in life?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `data.products` is bound to a text field, i.e., only one value, and you're trying to iterate over it.  Other than that, you'd also do `product in data.products`, not `{{data.products}}`

Comment: it should take the data from the http request while typing in the input field and then show the result with ngrepeat.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
exports.SearchBarController = function($scope, $http) {
  
  $scope.update = function() {
    var query = encodeURIComponent($scope.searchText);

    $http.
      get('/api/v1/product/text/' + query).
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.results = data.products;
      });
  };

  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$emit('SearchBarController');
  }, 0);
};
```

```html
<div class="search-bar-wrapper">
  <div ng-controller="SearchBarController">
      <input type="text" class="search-bar-input" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="update()">
        <div class="product" ng-repeat="product in results">
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks your post did some clarification, but it still does not work..

Comment: Actually only the ngcontroller div got me in trouble according to my MVC, thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. I just wanted you to figure out the problem.